# Why is a float type object not callable here?

Tags: python, error-handling, numerical-methods, taylor-series

I'm trying to make a Taylor series in Python and I don't know how to remove this error:

```
x=Symbol("x")

def f(x):
    return ((math.e)**x)*sin(x)

y=f(x)

print(y.diff(x))

def Taylor(f,x,m,a):
    y=f(x)
    y2=f
    yargliige=0
    viga = 10**(-m)
    n=0
    while True:
        if n>10:
           return yargliige,n
        else:
           yargliige+=(y(x)*(x-a)**n)/(factorial(n))
           y=y.diff(x)
           if abs(yargliige(x)-f(x))<viga:
              return yargliige,n
        n+=1

print(Taylor(f,-0.3,3,-1))
```

Error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arman\Desktop\Numbrilised meetodid\praktikum10.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(Taylor(f,-0.3,3,-1))
  File "C:\Users\arman\Desktop\Numbrilised meetodid\praktikum10.py", line 25, in Taylor
    yargliige+=(y(x)*(x-a)**n)/(factorial(n))
TypeError: 'Float' object is not callable
```

It seems that the original function doesn't accept float, which seems ridiculous.

Comment: What does `y(x)` mean? Because to Python, it means calling the function `y` with argument `x`. Also, which library is providing `Symbol`? You might want to tag that library.

Comment: Please remove not used declarations like the first definitions of `x` and `y` from the question code. After that it should be clear that `y=y.diff(x)` tries to do something impossible to floating point numbers.

Comment: Sympy is providing Symbol. I now got another error message that function object has no attribute "diff". I need to differentiate the function described in f(x) and and then put a value into it. How is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already called `y = f(x)` which stores the returned `float` from the function `f`.
You can not do `y()` as `y` is not callable.
Change `y = f(x)` to `y = f` and it should solve your use case.

Comment: I now get the error that function object has no attribute "diff". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to call `yargliige` as a function `yargliige(x)` which is not applicable since it's a variable not function.